# Firebase Dynamic Links in Unity

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-dynamic-links

Where should I put this chunk of code in order the listener function works every time I enter the app from the deep link?

Now in my unity mobile app I have this code in the initial load, however it does not work well.

The first case of entering the app from the deep link is not being handled. Only after initial load when I click the deep link my listener function works (as the listener is already set).

Is there any solution to this issue?

```c#
void Start() 
{
    DynamicLinks.DynamicLinkReceived += OnDynamicLink;
}

// Display the dynamic link received by the application.
void OnDynamicLink(object sender, EventArgs args) 
{
    var dynamicLinkEventArgs = args as ReceivedDynamicLinkEventArgs;
    Debug.LogFormat("Received dynamic link {0}", dynamicLinkEventArgs.ReceivedDynamicLink.Url.OriginalString);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Test this, feel free to edit.

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(WaitLoader()); //Loader
}

public void trueAwoken()
{
    DynamicLinks.DynamicLinkReceived += OnDynamicLink;
}
public IEnumerator WaitLoader()
{
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 5) // Potential for true load state 5 (increase this 0-1000+?, it depends on your build?)
    {
        i++;
        //Debug.Log("Waiting: " + i + "/" + Time.deltaTime);
        yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();
    }
    trueAwoken();
}
```

Comment: wouldn't this make it even worse since now you add the callback much later? OP's question sounds more like: You click on the link => App starts for the first time => not working since apparently callback not added yet when link is passed.

Comment: Try it and see if it works, and tell me the result if it calls the function though?